# Clickhouse: order by same order as table storage runs out of memory

Tags: clickhouse

I have billions of rows in a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample ( PN String,  
                      CHROM String,  
                      POS UInt32) 
ENGINE = MergeTree 
PARTITION BY PN 
ORDER BY (CHROM, POS) 
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

each PN having about 5 million rows

I want to return all rows in order of CHROM, POS

```sql
 select * from sample order by CHROM, POS
```

This runs out of memory.

Since the data is already stored in CHROM, POS order albeit partitioned by PN is there a way to 'stream' all data from the partitions and merge them in order without needing much memory.

Comment: The sorted data is stored in the scope of partition, therefore, to sort ALL ROWS from all partitions need to load whole content to memory and then sort it. Probably using the partition key as *PARTITION BY CHROM* or *PARTITION BY CHROM, POS* will work much better. As alternative, you can enable external sort (see  [max_bytes_before_external_sort](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#select-order-by)) to collect pre-sorted data on disk instead of memory.

Comment: @vladimir Yes - this does help PARTITION BY CHROM - thanks! It still takes quite a bit of memory but not as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorted data is stored in the scope of partition, therefore, to sort ALL ROWS from all partitions need to load whole content to memory and then sort it.

Using the partition key as *PARTITION BY CHROM* or *PARTITION BY (CHROM, POS)* will work much better.

As alternative, you can enable external sort (see [max_bytes_before_external_sort](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#select-order-by)) to collect pre-sorted data on disk instead of memory.